# I can access private variables in Java

Tags: java

**someObj.java**

---

```
public class someObj {
        private int data;

        someObj(int initVal) {
            data = initVal;
        }
        int getAnotherObjectData(someObj bar) {
            return bar.data;
        } 
}
```

---

### **Tester.java**

```
    someObj foo = new someObj(30);
    someObj bar = new someObj(40);
    System.out.println(bar.getAnotherObjectData(foo));
```

---

In result, I can get '30'.
Why I can access another Object's private variable data?

Comment: Because it's the same class.

Comment: If a variable is private, it means you can't access it outside the class where it's declared.  It doesn't mean that you can't access it from another object of the same class.

Comment: More specific duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17027139

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's the same class implementation, it means that you are writing this class by yourself, so you can control it 100%. So it's not a problem if you can access other objects of the same type as well. Such feature can be useful when implementing `equals` or `clone` methods like this:

```
public class MyObj {
    private int a;
    private long b;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        MyObj other = (MyObj) obj;
        if (a != other.a)
            return false;
        if (b != other.b)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Without field access for proper `equals` implementation you would need to have non-private getters for all fields which may be not desired in many cases.