# Can a private member of a new object be accessed from inside a method in the class definition of that object?

Tags: java, inheritance, private

This is how my class definition goes:

```
public class ArrayBag implements Bag {
    /** 
     * The array used to store the items in the bag.
     */
    private Object[] items;

    /** 
     * The number of items in the bag.
     */
    private int numItems;
```

... and so on...

This is a method in the class definition, where a new object of this class is created inside the method:

```
 //creates and returns an Arraybag that is the union of the called Arraybag and the parameter bag
 public bag unionWith(Bag other) {

     if (other == null)
           throw new IllegalArgumentException(); 

     int cap = this.capacity() + other.capacity();

     //new object created here      
     ArrayBag newbag = new ArrayBag(cap);

     for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {

           if (other.contains(items[i])) 

                 newbag.add(items[i]);

     }

     for (int i = 0; i < newbag.numItems(); i++)

        //Can I use "newbag.items[i]"?
        if (numOccur(newbag.items[i]))


 }
```

My question is, can I access the Object[] items of the newbag object from inside this method definition? Like this: newbag.items[i]

Comment: Why not test and see yourself? You've already written your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it.

It is feasable to do:

```
public class AClass {
    private int privateInteger;
    public AClass() {
        privateInteger = 5;
    }
    // First way 
    public void accessFromLocalInstance() {
        AClass localInstanceOfClass = new AClass()
        int valueOfLocalInstance = localInstanceOfClass.privateInteger;
    }
    // Second way
    public void accessFromInstance(AClass instance) {
        int valueOfInstance = instance.privateInteger;
    }
}
```

because

> "private" means restricted to this class, not restricted to this object.

See [Access private field of another object in same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027139/access-private-field-of-another-object-in-same-class)