# Pylint W0212 protected-access

Tags: python, private-members, pylint

In Python, prefixing with one underscore indicates that a member should not be accessed outside of its class.  This seems to be on a per-class basis like [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027139/access-private-field-of-another-object-in-same-class) and [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921185/why-do-objects-of-the-same-class-have-access-to-each-others-private-data).

However, pylint seems to enforce this convention on a per-object basis.  Is there a way to allow per-class access without resorting to `#pylint: disable=protected-access`?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._b = 5

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._b == other._b
```

Result:

```
pylint a.py
a.py:6: W0212(protected-access) Access to a protected member _b of a client class
```

Pylint describes the message [here](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0212).

Comment: duck typing and __eq__ overloading can be dangerous. I recommend also testing self.__class__ ==  other.__class__

Comment: Related (but with Pycharm): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736044/python-access-to-a-protected-member-of-a-class

Comment: See also [pylint issue #1802](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1802).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

pylint doesn't know of which type `other` is (how should it, you can compare an instance of A to everything), therefore the warning. I don't think there is a way around disabling the warning.

You can disable the warning for only that one line with appending `# pylint: disable=W0212` to that line.

Comment: Or `# pylint: disable=protected-access`

Comment: @DavidBeauchemin Is `pylint` able to perform introspection like `mypy`? The error in the example still issues for me even if I put `assert isinstance(other, A)` before the `return` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Christian Geier is right about why you're getting the error, and how to disable it.

I'd encourage you to consider changing your code, though: pylint is telling you something important. From your example code looks like you want to use eq compare objects of class A to other objects of class A, but your example won't guarantee that a caller won't try `A() == C()`. Returning `True` when you check `Circle()._radius == Sphere._radius` seems likely to cause problems.

See [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes) for discussion of how to handle this.