# Is a class automatically a friend of itself

Tags: c++

Why does this work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA(int id) : my_id(id) { };

    ClassA * makeNewA(int id)
    {
        ClassA *a = new ClassA(id);
        printf("ClassA made with id %d\n", a->getId());
        return a;
    };

private:
    int getId() {
        return my_id;
    };

private:
    int my_id;
};

int main()
{
    ClassA a(1);
    ClassA *b = a.makeNewA(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Irrespective of whether or not it's a good idea, why does it work? The public function `ClassA::makeNewA(int)` instantiates a new ClassA and then calls a private function `getId()` using the new object. Is a class automatically a friend of itself?

Thanks

Comment: Classes are always friend of themselfs.

Comment: Maybe a better way to think about it is that C++ encapsulation is class level, not object level.

Comment: @NirFriedman: Except that that isn't strictly true - You can't access `protected` members of another object, even from an object who has inherited the same members.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is intentional that a class's `public` methods can access its own `private` members, even if that method is acting on a different instance.

I guess one could say that a class automatically is a "friend" of itself.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, yes, the class is friend of itself, but better explanation would be that:

> In C++ access control works on per-class basis, not on per-object basis.

(copied from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6921318))

Note that this applies also to other languages, for example [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17027139) (in which you don't have *friends*) where access control also works on *per-class* basis.

Answer (score 2):

> All class methods, static or not, are automatically "friends" of the
>   class. Friend is used to allow external functions and classes access
>   to a class. The class is always its own "friend".