# How to link two nodes without a stackoverflow?

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to get two nodes to link together. When `n` adds `s` as a link, `s` should also update to add `n` as a link. But the code calls itself and gets stuck in an infinite loop, then overflows. How can I get the nodes to assign to each other, but not recursively assign themselves?

```
public class Node {
    Set<Node> connections = new HashSet<Node>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Node n = new Node();
        Node s = new Node();
        n.addNode(s);
    }

    public Node() {

    }
    public void addNode(Node newNode) {
        connections.add(newNode);
        newNode.addNode(this);
    }
}
```

Update: I added this code to have the method call another `setter` method.

```
   public void addNode(Node newNode) {
        connections.add(newNode);
        newNode.addSingleNode(this);
    }
    protected void addSingleNode(Node newNode) {
        connections.add(newNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: With the update your issue seems **solved**. Or are any questions left?

Comment: All good, had to wait for the timeout.

Comment: Ah okay. Just got confused by your edit of the question. Normally you wouldn't include the solution in the question by editing. Thus I thought you have a follow-up question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just access the other's node member directly:

```
public void addNode(Node newNode) {
    connections.add(newNode);
    newNode.connections.add(this);
}
```

An arguably "cleaner" way of doing this is to encapsulate this "logic" in a method:

```
private void addConnection(Node newConnection) {
    connections.add(newConnection);
}

public void addNode(Node newNode) {
    addConnection(newNode);
    newNode.addConnection(this);
}
```

Comment: Any downside to the direct way, or any reason to use the "cleaner" way?

Comment: The downside is **cluttering**, more methods can clutter your code. However there are many pros: You now have a place to easily insert logging, error-checking or future modifications. You can even totally exchange the internal data structures but the call to the method will remain the same.

Comment: @AlexG With `addConnection` being private, it's mostly a matter of style. If you make it protected, there's an argument to be made for it allowing you to extend the `Node` class and allow different extending classes to implement it differently.

Comment: Okay. To be clear, this is going to be extended by another class (it's for mapping Rooms in a game level). But they won't be modifying the code at all, so it can stay private I think. Btw I believe your "direct" method is off a little. Should be `newNode.connections.add(this)`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use recursion for this, and you won't have a problem.

```
public void addNode(Node newNode) {
    connections.add(newNode);
    newNode.connections.add(this);
}
```

This is allowed even if `connections` is private, because access to fields and methods is controlled on a per-class basis, not a per-object basis.

Comment: So, I realized this and thought about doing it, but I was worried because that means `connections` is being directly modified, without error checking. Would it be better to use a protected method to set it? I'll post an edit in a second.

Comment: You can add whatever error checking you like to this method.

Comment: Interesting. Wasn't aware of the `private` designation still allowing this to work. To be clear, you're saying that object A and object B can both modify each other's private variables, if they're the same type? Cool.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. `private` only hides the variable to **other classes**, not other instances of the same class (see [SO: Access private field of another object in same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027139/access-private-field-of-another-object-in-same-class) for an explanation and further links).

Comment: The way I think about this is that **code** written in class `X` has access to `private` members declared in class `X`.  If `Y` is a subclass of `X`, then an object of class `Y` can have code from both classes; but it's _where the code is written_ that dictates which private members it can see.  And yes, if a private member is declared in class `X`, then the code in class `X` can always access it, even it the member belongs to a different object from the one referenced by `this`.