# Comparable Class equals function works on private variable?

Tags: java, equals, private, comparable

Well my code works, but I just can't understand why a `private` variable works in this case, inside function `equals()`.

Or is it just a trick that if you call another object from inside the same kind of object structure then the `private` identifier doesn't count?

```
public class TestClass implements Comparable <TestClass> {
    private final String name;
    public TestClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof TestClass) {
            return ((TestClass) obj).name.equals(name); //<- how does this work, isn't name private?
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TestClass test) {
        int thisValue = hashCode();
        int otherValue = test.hashCode();
        if (thisValue < otherValue) {
            return -1;
        } else if (thisValue > otherValue) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these modifiers are class definition scoped not instance scoped. Check [JavaOO tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) and [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1):

> Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared private, then
>   access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the
>   top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or
>   constructor.

Comment: This is not meant for security but OO encapsulation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 1):

"Or it's just a trick if you call another Object from inside the same kind of Object structure then private identifier doesn't count?" - simply, yes.

**EDIT** Official explanation:

"The first (left-most) modifier used lets you control what other classes have access to a member field. For the moment, consider only public and private. Other access modifiers will be discussed later. public modifier—the field is accessible from all classes. private modifier—the field is accessible only within its own class."

(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

Comment: Can you add something substantial? Maybe a link to the JLS that describes this?

Comment: Here is the same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354728/why-have-class-level-access-modifiers-instead-of-object-level Nevermind thats C#

Comment: "The first (left-most) modifier used lets you control what other classes have access to a member field. For the moment, consider only public and private. Other access modifiers will be discussed later.

public modifier—the field is accessible from all classes.
private modifier—the field is accessible only within its own class."
(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

Comment: Edit it into your post so it's easier to see and you've got a decent answer :)